# Create a Azure Functions with the Java SDK

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sdk, azure-java-sdk

I want to create an Azure Functions with the Java SDK but I have some problem defining the trigger, my code to create the functions app is:

```
FunctionApp function = azure.appServices().functionApps().manager()
                                .functionApps()
                                .define(appName)
                                .withRegion(region)
                                .withExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup)
                                .withNewLinuxConsumptionPlan()
                                .withBuiltInImage(FunctionRuntimeStack.JAVA_11)
                                .withLatestRuntimeVersion()
                                .create();
```

And I want to define an EventHub Trigger but I don't know how I can do that, I see that my function object have the following method:

```
function.triggerFunction(functionName, payload);
```

What is the payload format? There is another way to do this?

Regards
Victor

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to create Java functions, there are Maven-based tooling and archetypes that use predefined Java templates to help you create projects with a specific function trigger.

Here are some references for you.

[Tutorial: Create a function in Java with an Event Hub trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-event-hub-cosmos-db)

[Create Azure function with Java and IntelliJ.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij)

[Create Azure function with Java and Eclipse.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-eclipse)

[Create Azure function with Java and VS Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-azurefunctions)

Comment: Hi @Tony, I need to create a Python Azure Functions using the Azure Java SDK, my problem is that the SDK is not well documented and I don't know the parameters meaning.